# logstash Input painfully slow while fetching messages from activemq topic

Tags: logstash, activemq-classic, logstash-configuration, jms-topic

I have configured JMS input in logstash to subscribe to JMS topic messages and push messages to elastic search.

```
input {

  jms {
      id => "my_first_jms"
      yaml_file => "D:\softwares\logstash-6.4.0\config\jms-amq.yml"
      yaml_section => "dev"
      use_jms_timestamp => true
      pub_sub => true
      destination => "mytopic"
#     threads => 50
    }
}

filter {
    json{
      source => "message"
    }

}

output {
    stdout { codec => json }

    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ['http://localhost:9401']
      index => "jmsindex"
  }
}
```

System specs:

```
RAM: 16 GB
Type: 64 bit
Processor: Intel i5-4570T CPU @ 2.9 GHz
```

This is extremely slow. Like 1 message every 3-4 minutes. How should I debug to figure out what is missing?

Note: Before this, I was doing this with @JMSListener in java and that could process 200-300 records per sec easily.

Comment: Are messages being sent to `mytopic` more quickly than you are receiving them? If so, how did you confirm this was the case?

Comment: I am pushing 5 records every second. Confirmed through http://localhost:8161/admin/topics.jsp page of ACTIVEMQ.

Comment: Also, if I use queues instead of topic its super fast. I have an intuition that this has to do something with slow acknowledgements.

Comment: But why would message acknowledgements be working differently between a queue and topic? When you tested with a queue were you also still outputting to elasticsearch?

Comment: I was thinking maybe `pub_sub` internally works differently. That's it. Also while testing for a topic/queue, the same config was used. Just commented out `pub_sub`.

Comment: Have you checked if the issue is not on the elasticsearch side? To check this, I'd remove the elasticsearch output and see how it goes.

Comment: I removed elasticsearch and tried `null` as well as `file` in output.

Comment: If you got the same results, I don't have any other idea.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for trying though.