# convert string to array based on pattern in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-filter

My original data.

```
{
  message: {
      data: "["1,2","3,4","5,6"]"
  }
}
```

Now I want to convert value of data field to an array.
So it should become:

```
{
  message: {
      data: ["1,2", "3,4", "5,6"]
  }
}
```

By using

```
mutate {
    gsub => ["data", "[\[\]]", ""]
  }
```

I got rid of square brackets.

After this, I tried splitting based on commas. But that won't work. Since my data has commas as well.

I tried writing a [dissect block](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.6/plugins-filters-dissect.html) but that is not useful.

So how should I go ahead with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the json filter? If the data field always contains valid json data, you use the json filter like this:

```
json {
    source => "data"
    target => "data"
}
```

Using `target => "data"` will overwrite the data field.

Comment: Will try this and reply back

Comment: I already have `json{
   source => "message"
 }`. Should I add your snippet after mine?

Comment: It worked correctly after adding both `json{ source => "message" }` and then json `{
    source => "data"
    target => "data"
}` Could you add an exlpanation why this works. Also, after fiddling I found that removing any of the 2 filters or removing `target` from 2nd filter gives undesired result. Would you care to explain why this works.

Comment: I found https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html to be a bit confusing,

Comment: The events received are managed as json object, with fields being the attribute-value pairs. One of them, in your case, is the field message. `json{ source => "message" }` is calling the json filter on the field called message, which will try to parse the message field as json; if the parsing is successful, the resulting json is added to the event in the root of the json.

Comment: Wit the ` target => "data"` option in the json filter, the json filter will add the resulting json as children of the field data, replacing anything that was there before: in your case, it replaces the string by the array.

Comment: Ok. I understood the `target` part. So, when filter `json{ source => "message" }` runs. It adds the parsed JSON to my ouput JSON or the **content** of the parsed JSON to output JSON?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. When `json{ source => "message" }` parse `{"key":"val"}`, it will add a field called key of value val to the logstash event, at the root level.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you could attempt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54392216/5051731) question it would b great

Comment: It's not something I'm familiar with and I can't exactly try to reproduce it, unlike this question. I'll still take a look.